# How to change reference of Base object to Derived which was instatiated as Derived type

Tags: c#, inheritance

Why am i not able to access M3 method from Derived ?
Intellisense shows only M1 and M2 from Base class.
How can i change the reference of bc from Base type to Refernce Type, 
so that i can access M3 method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base bc = new Derived();
        bc.M3():// error
    }
}

class Base
{
    public void M1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("M1 from BASE.");
    }
    public void M2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("M2 from BASE.");
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public void M3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("M3 from DERIVED.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler must resolve the name `M3` at compile time.  This is being invoked on a reference of type `Base` and `Base` has no member of that name.  The fact that it happens to point to an instance of `Derived` at runtime has no bearing here because the compiler is looking at the information available at compile time.

Yes in this specific case the compiler could see that `bc` is always initialized to a `Derived` value hence it should look there.  However this is just not how the c# compiler works.  It looks only at the compile time type of the reference involved

Comment: But how can i change the reference type of bc to Derived Type, so that i can access M3 method. Is there any other way to force the change ?

Comment: @RAZER you could use a cast operation `((Derived)bc).M3()` or simply change the type of `bc` to `Derived` at the declaration site.  `Derived bc = new Derived()`

Answer (score 1):

Because you upper cast your type to a base class, so the set of all available members is reduces to those ones available in `Base`.

```
Derived bc = new Derived();
bc.M3():// CORRECT
```

or simply

```
var bc = new Derived();
bc.M3():// CORRECT
```

If you need to work with `Base` class for polymorphism in your app and need to use `M3()` consider moving it in `Base` class

Answer (score 1):

Because the only guarantee the `bc` reference carries is that it will refer to an instance of `Base` or something derived from `Base`.

Consider if the code was changed like this:

```
Base bc = new Derived();
if(DateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
  bc = new Base();
}
bc.M3();
```

That would be perfectly legal, as the guarantees of `bc` are still fullfilled.

There are two possible ways to deal with this: Casting and polymorphism.

Casting means that you tell the compiler that you know that this is indeed a `Derived` instance, even though the reference is of `Base` type.

```
Base bc = new Derived();
if(bc is Derived)
{
  ((Derived)bc).M3();
}
```

The other is to declare the M3 function in the base class and then override it in the derived class

```
class Base
{
   // Other stuff...

   public virtual void M3()
   {
   }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void M3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("M3 from DERIVED.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `bc` is declared as of type `Base`. You need to cast it first

```
    Base bc = new Derived();
    ((Derived)bc).M3()
```

This will be a runtime error if `bc` was actually of type `Base` instead of `Derived`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler only sees that you are working with a variable of type Base.

Take the following code:

```
Base bc = null;

if (SomeValue)
{
    bc = new Base();
}
else
{
   bc = new Derived();
}
```

The value of SomeValue can vary at runtime. This means that the compiler won't know the actual type of `bc` at compile time. This is the whole idea of base classes. You share the same interface as your base class but you can change the implementation of methods.

You can however cast a type to another type:

```
Derived dc = bc as Derived;

if ( dc != null ) // cast succeeded so we have a Derived
{
    dc.M3();
}
```

To only check if a type is of another type you can use `is`: `if (dc is Derived)`.

Be aware however of the dangers of doing this. This way, you are littering your code with all type specific checks which makes it harder to understand and maintain. If you want to know more about this read something on S[OLID patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).